# How to automate building a VM from an ISO file

Tags: linux, jenkins, automation, devops, iso

I have a Jenkins pipeline, its output is an ISO file (linux). After getting the file I have to prepare a new VM guest in Virtualbox then attaching the ISO file to that VM and wait till the installation is done to ensure the ISO file does not have any problem which is a quite long process and a time consuming as well, so I am trying to automate this process if possible.

I found [virtualBox plugin for Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/virtualbox/) but it is very old and it is just managing a server (not spinning up a VM from ISO).

As a proof of concept I tried to start VM from the VirtualBox's command line (*VirtualBoxManage*) but I am getting below error message :

```
VBoxManage: error: Unattended installation is not supported for guest type 'Linux_64'
```

I tried Qemu as well but Unfortunately, I am not able to install KVM as all the servers/PCs do not support virtualization !

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated .. Thanks in advance.

### Notes:

1. Jenkin is running in kubernetes but I have no issue to make it runs as a standalone directly in the host.
2. I am using Jenkins to generate a Linux ISO because I am customizing the basic ISO by adding some RPMs and modifying kickstart file.

Answer (score 0):

Packer by HashiCorp can be used for this job.

I am also create a customize Linux distribution ISO. To achieve this, I have a Jenkins Pipeline with this steps:

1. Build a linux distribution ISO.
2. Build and export as OVF a virtual machine on VMware Vsphere using Packer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).